# How do I remove all whitespaces except those between words with Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, removing-whitespace

```
  var str=" hello world! , this is Cecy ";
  var r1=/^\s|\s$/g;
  console.log(str.match(r1));
  console.log(str.replace(r1,''))
```

Here, the output I expect is "hello world!,this is Cecy", which means remove whitespaces in the beginning and the end of the string, and the whitespace before and after the non-word characters. 
The output I have right now is"hello world! , this is Cecy", I don't know who to remove the whitespace before and after "," while keep whitespace between "o" and "w" (and between other word characters).

p.s. I feel I can use group here, but don't know who

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Method 1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/JUlTed/3)

```
\B\s+|\s+\B
```

- `\B` Matches a location where `\b` doesn't match
- `\s+` Matches one or more whitespace characters

```js
const r = /\B\s+|\s+\B/g
const s = ` hello world! , this is Cecy `

console.log(s.replace(r, ''))
```

---

#### Method 2

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/JUlTed/2).

```
(?!\b\s+\b)\s+
```

- `(?!\b +\b)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

  - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
  - `\s+` Match any whitespace character one or more times
  - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `\s+` Match any whitespace character one or more times

```js
const r = /(?!\b\s+\b)\s+/g
const s = ` hello world! , this is Cecy `

console.log(s.replace(r, ''))
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `\B\s+|\s+\B` works. Shouldn't it destroy the `\B` it matches in the process?

Comment: @Zenoo `\b` and `\B` are **zero-length** assertions. So, to put it simply, they match locations and not characters.

Comment: Well, I indeed feel dumb ... Thanks for the clarification :D

Comment: @Zenoo no worries :) regex is complicated

Comment: I don't quit understand it... (?!\b\s+\b)\s+ , for me it means match the whitespaces if there is no b\s+\b before it. And  \b\s+\b means the whitespaces which have word before AND after them.  How does this work

Comment: @XinyiLi `(?!)` is a lookahead, so it's going to look at the current position to see if it matches, and if it does, it'll ignore that. Negating these locations means that we're actually matching any locations where `\B\s+\b` or `\b\s+\B` or `\B\s+\B` matches.

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the RegEx [`^\s|\s$|(?<=\B)\s|\s(?=\B)`](https://regex101.com/r/AgdBXv/1)

- `^\s` handles the case of a space at the beginning
- `\s$` handles the case of a space at the end
- `(?<=\B)\s` handles the case of a space after a non-word char
- `\s(?=\B)` handles the case of a space before a non-word char

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/AgdBXv/1)

***EDIT :*** As ctwheels pointed out, `\b` is a zero-length assertion, therefore you don't need any lookbehind nor lookahead.

*Here is a shorter, simpler version :* `^\s|\s$|\B\s|\s\B`

```js
var str = " hello world! , this is Cecy ";
console.log(str.replace(/^\s|\s$|\B\s|\s\B/g, ''));
```

Comment: Anyway, `/^\s|\s$|(?<=\B)\s|\s(?=\B)/g` won't work in Node. You must remove the lookbehind.

Comment: Only works in Chrome 62+ since lookbehinds have seldom support in JavaScript. See the [EMCA TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) for more information. This will only work if you're using a package like [`xregexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp)

Answer (score 1):

the method that your are looking for is trim()
https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

```
 var str = "       Hello World!       ";
console.log(str.trim())
```

Comment: Almost, OP specifically asked for removing all whitespace except between words, giving an example of `world! , this` -> `world!, this` which would fail your solution.

Comment: this does not remove the white space between `!` & `'`

Comment: this does not answer the question he specifically asked for regex

Answer (score -2):

yuo can use the following command

```
str.replace(/ /g,'')
```